# Using access token and refresh token in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reddit

I've written a React-Redux app that uses the Reddit API to retrieve an access token for the user to view posts. I'm currently saving the access token in `localStorage` for convenience but I'm certain it's not safe to do so, while I also haven't been able to write working code to use the refresh token to update the access token every hour. Help with and insight on this would be greatly appreciated (details and code can be seen at https://github.com/DavyK17/fgc-reddit/issues/12).

Answer (score 0):

The example in this page is good explained and it is working great :
[React Refresh Token example](https://www.bezkoder.com/react-refresh-token/)

Hope that answers your question